# Does fancybox v3.0 have show loading

Tags: fancybox-3

After making an upgrade from 2.x to 3.0 my application broke.
Does the new version have functions like

```
$.fancybox.showLoading();
$.fancybox.helpers.overlay.open();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no. v3 has different html structure. When you open image gallery, it loads current image, next and previous ones. Each of them has their own loading icon. This is because v3 is now "touchable" and user can drag slides while they are still loading.